# what is the most optimized between

Tags: javascript

i'm using mousemove event and as it executes each time possible, I want to optimize this and I think about these two possibilities:

```
ok = true;

function mousemove(e)
{
    if(ok == true)
    {
        ok = false;
        window.setTimeout(function(){ ok = true; }, 1000/60);//60 FPS
        //Code here
    }
}
```

and

```
lastTime = +new Date();

function mousemove(e)
{
    if(+new Date() - lastTime > 1/60)//60 FPS
    {
        lastTime = +new Date();
        //Code here
    }
}
```

So is it better to use window interval (or timeout) or use a timestamp?

(if you have another idea, I take!)

Thank you!

Comment: They are different.

Comment: @haim770 Because he wants to execute code when the mouse moves, but no more than 60 times a second.

Comment: What do the profilers in your target browsers say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is seeking for optimisations and [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for it.

Comment: i agree with @Rajesh, this question is not asking a question, and we have no idea what he even want to achieve with those functions.

Comment: My question is asked: is it best to use a timestamp or a timeout. 
I'm making a custom drag

Comment: I would say: neither. Make two async methods, which will be synced by using primitive or immutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

Within the event I would simply update a variable (e.g. position of the mouse) and within a second event (e.g. requestAnimationFrame) I would read that variable and reset it. So in the next loop I check if it has a valid value and compute it again (cause the user moved the mouse further) or it is still not set (cause the user didn't move the mouse any further).

```
let currentPosition = null;

function onPaint() {
    if(currentPosition !== null) {
        let paintPosition = currentPosition;
        currentPosition = null;

        // ToDo: update visualization by using paintPosition...
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(onPaint);
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
    currentPosition = e.position;        
}

onPaint();
```

Comment: The problem is that all my code is in the mousemove, no other event :)

Comment: Then simply refactor your code. That's daily buisness.

Answer (score 0):

Using an interval means having a function that is executed 60 times per second, even if the mouse is not being used.
Checking if the right period has passed within the mouse event callback is only executed when needed.

So I'd discard the interval approach (same for timeout):

```
(function () {
    var time=+new Date();
    myElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
        if (time- (+new Date()) < 60) return;
        time=+new Date();
        /* Here my logic*/
    });
})()
```

Comment: Yeah I know it and what about a timeout vs timestamp as said?

Comment: So, you go on option 2?

Comment: Just check when the even occurs if the time has passed, don't use setInterval or setTimeout